# Passing props to child component with other object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
function NavigationItem(props){                   
return( 
<TouchableOpacity 
onPress={(view)=>props.navigation.closeDrawer()}>     
<Text style={customStyle.headerStyle}>{props.titleValue}</Text>
<View style={customStyle.dividerStyle}  />
  </TouchableOpacity>
  ) 
}
```

In the above function, you can see that I am receiving data in single argument props and other
an object which is passing below. But I don't know why it's working I am passing two values one is props and the other is object titlevalue in the given below syntax. I hope you understand my query I am new in react native.

```
<NavigationItem {...props} titleValue={"Profile"} ></NavigationItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

**USING COMPONENT** :

First of all, you have to understand what is props in react native and how you pass them to other component.

```
<NavigationItem {...props} titleValue={"Profile"} ></NavigationItem>
```

So in you statement `{...props}` and `title` are props and what you doing is passing all of your existing props `( as {...props})` + `title` to some other component.

**DEFINING COMPONENT** :

so what ever props are passed to you component for creation will be received in inside statement as `props`

```
function NavigationItem(props)
```

**POINT TO BE NOTED**

Don't get confused between props name as parameter in `function NavigationItem(props)` you can use any name here it can be `kamal`. but after using `kamal` you have to access your passed props like `kamal.title`.

One thing more its not a good approach to pass whole props as `{...props}` to some other component. it will `re-render` it if anything changes inside `{...props}`.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your reply, Now I have clear my dought I was confusion in passing data to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to [Spread Attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) `{...props}` means you are not passing props as it is rather props properties.

so as giving

`<NavigationItem {...props} titleValue={"Profile"} ></NavigationItem>`

after spread (assuming props have only `navigation` property) for understanding adding this code but it actually done by spread attribute.

`<NavigationItem navigation={navigation} titleValue={"Profile"} ></NavigationItem>`

now `NavigationItem` component has props as *navigation* and *titleValue*